# Promise all convention approaches

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

we did some code review and it the code before was like following:

```
run:  () =>{

    var _this = this;
    return Promise.all([
        //Get  command
        cp.getCommand(constants.HB),
        //Find port
        cp.findPort()
        ]).spread((r1, r2) => {
        ...
```

After the code review my colleagues suggest to change it to the following which I disagree 
 since you need to add unnecessary code (the array & push) and Im not sure that this is more readable, what do you think?

```
 run: function () => {

    var _this = this;

    var promiseArray = [];
    //Get  command
    promiseArray.push(cp.getCommand(constants.HB));
    //Find port
    promiseArray.push(cp.findPort());

    return Promise.all(promiseArray)
        .spread((r1, r2) => {
```

Comment: It's entirely opinion based, and unrelated to promises. As a tip you can use `.join` instead of the two options and get even nicer syntax. `Promise.join(cp.getCommand(constants.HB), cb.findPort(), (r1, r2) => { ...`

Comment: The second one is really horrible code. Use array literals when the contents are static. There's nothing gained here by using `push`.

Comment: Given you're using ES6, you might use `.then(([r1, r2]) => …)` instead of `spread`. Or, as Benjamin says, just go for Bluebird's `Promise.join`

Comment: What did your colleagues give as the reason for their suggested change?

Comment: `After the code review my colleagues suggest to change it to the following` - your colleagues don't know ES2015+ very well at all ... I don't think that would even parse

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Thank you, just to verify the only difference with the Join is that you dont need the [] ?

Comment: @Bergi - Thank you! one question, do you think that in some other cases it is good to use array for promises or this is bed in most of the cases ?

Comment: @Bergi - btw I tried to use the then like you said and I got error ... ]).then(([r1, r2]) => …) , SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ .. any idea? can you provide general example of some referance to docs?

Comment: @JohnJerrby: Sure there are, usually when you add promises dynamically or conditionally to the array. (but if you're doing only a loop, I'd recommend `map`)

Comment: @JohnJerrby: Re syntax error: you're coding ES6, right? It does support array destructuring in parameters. Check your browser or transpiler support.

Comment: @Bergi -  Thank you, yes Im using ES6 in node.js version 4.4, which is not working i guess , there is some example which I can take as reference?since maybe Im missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no particular reason to put the promises into an explicitly declared array before passing them to `Promise.all()` so it's pretty hard to defend that the second option is "better" than the first option.

In fact, you could easily make a case that the second option just creates an unnecessary named variable containing the intermediate array and does unnecessary `.push()` function calls.

In the end, there is no absolute right or wrong here.  This is merely a matter of opinion on coding style.  Code reviews are often part defensible logic and part reviewer's opinion.  It appears you just ran into some opinion where the reviewer has a different opinion than you do.

If you want to push back on a review issue like this, then you should ask them to defend why they their method is necessarily better than your first approach.